# Apache Superset integration in web apps

Tags: apache-superset

I'm new to Apache Superset and have some questions. Hope you guys can answer them:

(1) Is it possible to integrate dashboards via IFrames?

(2) Are there any other ways to integrate dashboards into other web applications.

(3) I found the superset-ui project. It seems to provide the same components that are used in Superset (at least the legacy once). But these are just the pure JavaScript components, right?. I'm wondering how to fetch the data to the components? Does Superset provide an API to fetch the data or do I have to write a backend services on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answering your questions the best I can:

**(1) Integrate dashboards via IFrames**
Yes you can. You can either set the datasource of the dashboard as "public" using the provided public role, or you can have the users authenticate in Superset within the iframe - [source](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/2571)

**(2) Other ways to integrate dashboards into other web applications.**
You can set up some sort of automated authentication with something like a reverse proxy (using "remote user" authentication) that would have common authentication for both your applications. There is a [demo (somewhat old - 2018) for django and superset integration](https://github.com/sairamkrish/django-demo-project) by Sairam Krish

**(3) How to fetch the data to the components**
See issues [#4708](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/4708) [#5581](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/5581) [#7941](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/7941)

Note that **[Superset is preparing the version 1.0 release](https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-roadmap/blob/master/Superset%201.0/Presentation_Superset_Meetup_2020_11_11_Roadmap.pdf)** that will have a lot of improvements and changes, than can impact the way you can integrate Superset with other apps.

To finish this answer, let me point you to this article by Sairam Krish: *[Apache Superset - Thoughts on custom authentication, running as Docker, having public dashboards and behind Nginx](https://sairamkrish.medium.com/apache-superset-custom-authentication-and-integrate-with-other-micro-services-8217956273c1)*

Answer (score 0):

Embed the complete dashboard using the following code. Courtesy of [heaven00](https://github.com/cbgaindia/union-budget-board/issues/7#issuecomment-358947111)

```
<iframe
  width="1600"
  height="1600"
  seamless
  frameBorder="0"
  scrolling="yes"
  src="http://52.214.125.248:8088/superset/dashboard/8/?preselect_filters=%7B%2252%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%5B%22Police.csv%22%5D%2C%22particulars_1%22%3A%5B%22Establishment%20Expenditure%20of%20the%20Centre%22%5D%2C%22particulars_2%22%3A%5B%22Central%20Armed%20Police%20Forces%22%5D%7D%7D&standalone=true&height=1600"
>
</iframe>
```